# Multiple Source To a copy activity in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

On-premise stored procedure accepts two parameters and  returns multiple records, which needs to be written to azure data lake store(adls).
Those 2 parameters are existing in two different files, which I trying to  read from 2 individual Look UP activities in ADF.

Unfortunately Copy activity where stored procedure is being executed, accepts only one dependent input link. So how can I pass these two parameters to copy activity?

Are there any work arounds to look up two different files and pass the returned values to stored procedure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

suppose the 2 parameters store in two different blob files and the stored procedure is invoked in copy source side, please follow the below step:

1. Create two lookup activity referring to blob dataset, this step is for look up 2 parameters. Let's suppose these 2 parameters reside in the first row of the 2 files respectively, so check the "First row only" in lookup activity.
2. Create a copy activity with the condition of these two lookup activity running successfully, invoke the stored procedure in copy source.
3. Import the two parameters of the stored procedure, here we name them as "para1" and "para2", the pass "@activity('Lookup1').output.firstRow" and "@activity('Lookup2').output.firstRow" to 2 parameters.

The following pic shows this example:
[image]

Comment: Well., How about when you have multiple columns(delimited columns) in a single row.  Out of which you need to pick one column value as parameter and pass it to next activity? Additionally, I've header in the lookup file.

Comment: The way to access lookup activity output data depends on the structure of the output, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-lookup-activity#use-the-lookup-activity-result-in-a-subsequent-activity this link gives you details about that.